# Incomplete BeautifulSoup scrape while using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Backcountry.com review section. The site uses a dynamic load more section, ie the url doesn't change when you want to load more reviews. I am using Selenium webdriver to interact with the button that loads more review and BeautifulSoup to scrape the reviews.

I was able to successfully interact with the load more button and load all the reviews available. I was also able to scrape the initial reviews that appear before you try the load more button.

IN SUMMARY: I can interact with the load more button, I can scrape the initial reviews available but I cannot scrape all the reviews that are available after I load all.

I have tried to change the html tags to see if that makes a difference. I have tried to increase the sleep time in case the scraper didn't have enough time to complete its job.

```
# URL and Request code for BeautifulSoup

url_filter_bc = 'https://www.backcountry.com/msr-miniworks-ex-ceramic-water-filter?skid=CAS0479-CE-ONSI&ti=U2VhcmNoIFJlc3VsdHM6bXNyOjE6MTE6bXNy'
res_filter_bc = requests.get(url_filter_bc, headers = {'User-agent' : 'notbot'})


# Function that scrapes the reivews

def scrape_bc(request, website):
    newlist = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'lxml')
    newsoup = soup.find('div', {'id': 'the-wall'})
    reviews = newsoup.find('section', {'id': 'wall-content'})

    for row in reviews.find_all('section', {'class': 'upc-single user-content-review review'}):
        newdict = {}
        newdict['review']  = row.find('p', {'class': 'user-content__body description'}).text
        newdict['title']   = row.find('h3', {'class': 'user-content__title upc-title'}).text
        newdict['website'] = website

        newlist.append(newdict)

    df = pd.DataFrame(newlist)
    return df


# function that uses Selenium and combines that with the scraper function to output a pandas Dataframe

def full_bc(url, website):
    driver = connect_to_page(url, headless=False)
    request = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-agent' : 'notbot'})
    time.sleep(5)
    full_df = pd.DataFrame()
    while True:
        try:
            loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn js-load-more-btn btn-secondary pdp-wall__load-more-btn']")
            time.sleep(2)
            loadMoreButton.click()
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            print('Done Loading More')

#             full_json = driver.page_source
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
            temp_df = scrape_bc(request, website)

            full_df = pd.concat([full_df, temp_df], ignore_index = True)

            time.sleep(7)
            driver.quit()
            break

    return  full_df
```

I expect a pandas dataframe with 113 rows and three columns.
I am getting a pandas datafram with 18 rows and three columns.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you clicked `loadMoreButton` and loaded more reviews. But you keep feeding to `scrape_bc` the same `request` content you downloaded once, totally separately from Selenium.

Replace `requests.get(...)` with `driver.page_source` and ensure you have `driver.page_source` in a loop before `scrape_bc(...)` call

```
request = driver.page_source
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
temp_df = scrape_bc(request, website)
```